# .net 4.6 and 4.7 already out... still no airspace fix for wpf hosting classic hwnd window?

Tags: .net, wpf, interop, winforms-interop

I integrated OpenSceneGraph in a WPF application. Thus OSG renders on the classic HWND and in that time the previous versions of .net had airspace problems when using a hwndhost (like winformshost) for having a handle. Thus I was forced to create some "write backbuffer to image and display on bitmap in memory" routine because bitmap can be integrated easy with wpf without airspace problems. Well, not the fastest but works...

However, there were rumours in the early previous of .net 4.6 that had a switch (IsRedirected, CompositionMode) that can be enabled to magically solve the problem... sadly, this switch did not apear in the release of 4.6.

Is there some change or release now that includes a solution to fix the interop airspace problems?

Comment: What is _airspace_?  Looks like you are the first person to use that tag

Comment: I guess there is a duplicate of your problem with answer "not possible", you can award a bounty to receive an updated answer if you want. Voting to close this one because you didn't present the problem at all.

Comment: It is a very fundamental issue that can't easily be wished away.  Nothing new in recent framework versions.  They did try [but have to give up on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21345373/17034).

Comment: @MickyD: airspace is the name for interop issues related to drawing when having two rendering methods (in this case WPF and WinForms). If you Google "airspace wpf" you'll find a lot about this.

Comment: @Sinatr: The Problem is that I don't find any information about latest changes (because problem is several years old, see answer below) and did not know that they don't have any plans to put this Feature into future releases. The answer is good. => no hope for solving in .net Framework directly anymore.

Comment: Given a problem would be presented clearly (it's currently not: no source code, no screenshot, just some uncommon term "airspace"), then someone may find a duplicate for you. You say answer is good. Is it? For you - maybe, for community - it's copy/paste from another answer, but I personally don't know if question there is the same to vote-close yours as duplicate.

Comment: Airspace is the typical term for that. I named the properties, maybe could have been formatted better. See the upvotes for the answer?

Comment: I think if it were called _"z-order"_ people would have a better understanding than _"airspace"_

Comment: But z-order already exist in wpf (and others) and does not imply different rendering techniques. Z-order is just about the rendering order in z-axis. Closely related but is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET 4.5 beta had this feature, but it was removed...

As noted in [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468667/146921) by [Glenn Slayden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147511/glenn-slayden) on a similar question, the feature **will not be included in any future releases**:

> ### [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Beta Readme](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/E/0/FE0F3C6E-9775-476D-A7DD-5E4659797F44/Net%20Framework%204.5%20Beta%20Readme_enu.html)
>
> 1.3.10 Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>
> > 1.3.10.1 HwndHost feature has been removed from WPF in the .NET Framework 4.5 Beta
> >
> > The .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview included a WPF HwndHost redirection feature. However, this feature ***had several known issues and has been removed from the .NET Framework 4.5 Beta.*** It will not be included in any future releases.
> >
> > To resolve this issue:
> >
> > No workaround is available.

Comment: The question should arguably have been marked as a duplicate of the link you provided

Comment: @MickyD: I agree, and I see now that is has been marked as a duplicate.